# How to implement language translator facility in an iphone application?

Tags: iphone

How to implement language translator facility in an iphone application ? 
I have found that for Online mode this works, using GOOGLE API :(for example)

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?q=nature&v=1.0&langpair=en%7Cja

But how to perform language translation in offline mode ? Any open source API available.

Is it allowed to use google translate API in iphone application ??

(Languages  : All languages which are supported by iPhone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natural language translation is an incredibly hard problem.  Given the limited storage and computational resources available to a mobile device, I'd say that your best bet would be to leverage an existing online service, like Google's translation engine.

Otherwise, you could check out the libraries mentioned in this question: "[Your favorite natural language parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88984/your-favorite-natural-language-parser)" to parse the language.  Translation after that point will be another challenge.  The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316386/translating-human-languages-in-python) point out one or two resources for Python, but that's not really compatible with the iPhone.