# Free API to translate English to Spanish in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, translation

I want to develop an application that translate a given sentence in `English` to `Spanish`, and vice-versa the limitation is that I don't have to use online facility like [Google Translator](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html).

I visited some links that says its not possible, some of them are

1. [How to implement language translator facility in an iphone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3699511/459624)
2. [Your favorite natural language parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/88984/459624) how do I use it, is there any API that uses it?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to translate entirely on the device, without an internet connection, you are in for an uphill task!

Comment: i know that, but is there anyone who has done this task i.e is there any free Api for this task

Comment: @AmitSingh soo! after two years later. did you find an api for this task? or i sould keep digging?

Comment: @Amourreux - I didn't find anything at that time, for now I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a free API where you can download and use it offline. You'd have to use something like the Google Translate API which needs an Internet Connection. Alternatively you could build your own parser and translation tool.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Apertium](http://www.apertium.org/) for this.

I see that there is an [Apertium offline translator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.apertium.android&hl=en) app for android.

The code is open source on sourceforge and can probably be adapted to an iPhone.

Comment: The Apple App Store has some restriction against GPL though, so it would only work on rooted iPhones. Discussion: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.nlp.apertium/1783/focus=1790