# How can I translate input text from one language to another using python?

Tags: python, translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Translating human languages in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316386/translating-human-languages-in-python)

I am trying to develop an application that can accept input from users and translate the input language to another language using python. I have tried to use the replace string function in python but it is not working. I also tried using the `gettext` module but I am not very sure it can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

*gettext* is a quite standard way for translating messages, strings etc. which are a part of your software, but not for translating user input.

To translate user input it is better to use 3rd  party services & APIs like Google Translate, Being Translator etc. Most of them have ready to run python interface. Some of them are paid services.